# Read multiple partitions using pyarrow

Tags: pyarrow, google-cloud-storage

I have a partitioned GCS path that has parquet files in it.
It is partitioned based on `fiscal_week`. I would like to read the data from these three partitions using pyarrow and convert it to `pandas` df.
I has more partitions with other `fiscal_week` in it

```
partitioned_paths = ['bucket/Stage/Adapted/MX/Retail/SALES/fiscal_week=202349/',
 'bucket/Stage/Adapted/MX/Retail/SALES/fiscal_week=202350/',
 'bucket/Stage/Adapted/MX/Retail/SALES/fiscal_week=202351/', ]
```

I tried this

```
dataset = pyarrow.dataset.dataset(
            partitioned_paths, 
            filesystem=gs,
        )
```

It throws the error

FileNotFoundError: 'bucket/Stage/Adapted/MX/Retail/SALES/fiscal_week=202349/'

But the path exists in GCS

Comment: Try to rename the fiscal_week directories by removing the equals sign.

Comment: It's possible that passing a list of directory doesn't work, only a list of (parquet) files.